# google charts table cannot display hellip

Tags: javascript, html, flask, google-visualization

I am trying to truncate strings for cells of `Google charts table`. At the end of each truncated string, I tried to add a `...` or hellip, but the table could not show the hellip. I tried the following code for truncating strings from the forum,

```js
function truncate(n, useWordBoundary) { 
if (this.length <= n) { return this; } 
var subString = this.substr(0, n - 1);
// '&hellip' won't work as well
return (useWordBoundary ? subString.substr(0, subString.lastIndexOf(' ')) : subString) + '...'; 
}
```

`allowHtml` is enabled when drawing the table.

I am wondering how to fix the issue.

UPDATE

I think the problem is coming from `flask`. I am using `flask` to do some server-client app coding. The `truncate` function (in a file called `truncate.js`) is put in `static/js` folder, while the client `html` is put in `templates` folder. When I linked `truncate.js` in the `html`, I couldn't get `...` to display in a truncated string no matter what. But if I just put `truncate` function in the `html` file, `...` can be displayed.

Another thing is it doesn't matter if `allowHtml` is on or off, the `...` always works as intended, but `&hellip` is not (it will be displayed as `&hellip` at the end of the truncated string). This I think is a bug in `google charts table`?

Many thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

looks like the problem lies within the `truncate` function

it uses `this` to reference the string to truncate,
try adding the string as another parameter instead...

here, the function is used in combination with a calculated column in a DataView

see following working snippet...

```js
google.charts.load('current', {
  callback: drawTable,
  packages: ['table']
});

function drawTable() {
  var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
  data.addColumn('string', 'Sentence');
  data.addColumn('number', 'Value');
  data.addColumn('boolean', 'Test');
  data.addRows([
    ['This is a long string that needs to be truncated',  10000, true],
    ['This is another, even longer string that needs to be truncated',  20000, true],
    ['This does not need truncated', 1000, false]
  ]);

  var view = new google.visualization.DataView(data);
  view.setColumns([{
    calc: function (dt, row) {
      return truncate(dt.getValue(row, 0), 20, true);
    },
    label: data.getColumnLabel(0),
    type: 'string',
  }, 1, 2]);


  var table = new google.visualization.Table(document.getElementById('table_div'));
  table.draw(view, {
    allowHtml: true
  });
}

function truncate(str, n, useWordBoundary) {
  if (str.length <= n) { return str; }
  var subString = str.substr(0, n - 1);
  return (useWordBoundary ? subString.substr(0, subString.lastIndexOf(' ')) : subString) + '&hellip;';
}
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="table_div"></div>
```

Comment: thx for the code, I am wondering what's wrong with using `this` to reference the string to be truncated here.

Comment: to use `this`, the function would need to be a prototype of `string` or part of a `string` class...

Comment: in order to use `&hellip;` -- __it must be followed by a semi-colon__ `;` -- changed answer above, see `truncate` function...